# Spring Boot Application Host on Docker Desktop on Windows

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, dockerfile, docker-desktop

I am using Docker Desktop Version 2.3.0.3 stable version
I have Created on Simple Spring Boot Rest App with Get Controller that prints "HELLO"
URL: **http://localhost:8090/hello**

I have created simple Dockerfile with properties given below:

```
From openjdk:16-jdk
ADD target/Hello.war Hello.war
EXPOSE 8090
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","Hello.war"]
```

So when I build and run this docker image the above API gets hit only through my "localhost" host

MY Run Command:

```
docker run -d -p 8090:8090 docker_spectra
```

Please Help How I can expose this API to a remote server in the same network by binding through IP as we do by changing the server.xml in Tomcat Web Server.

Please help !!!

Comment: Are you sure it's a docker problem? Are some other services on your PC reachable from other PCs in the same network? Maybe you have some firewall which blocks this specific port? Your run-command looks fine.

Comment: I have tried disabling firewall also.                                         Can you please help me what will be my ip for container port . It will be my system ipv4 or container ip(172. something) or any other ip which we see while ipconfig.

Comment: If you do `-p 8090:8090` it will bind the container's port 8090 to your host's port 8090. So for other PCs in the network it will be the IP of your PC where the docker container is running.

Comment: What do you get when you do a curl to your IP on port 8090?

Answer (score 0):

With below configuration of `Dockerfile` and `docker run` command. I am able to hit the API hosted in the Azure Cloud.

```
FROM openjdk:11
ADD target/leavemodule*.jar leavemodule.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/leavemodule.jar"]
```

and

```
docker run -d -p 8080:8080 --name leavemodule-service anandaili/leavemodule-service
```

You can see complete guide how I am building the docker image and deploying it here [leavemodule](https://github.com/dashrath-purohit/leavemodule/blob/master/README.md) and you can hit the swagger ui: http://13.95.3.6:8080/swagger-ui.html

Comment: Thanks for your response anand, But please read my question i am facing this issue on Windows 10 which is running docker desktop application, and you have given something related to cloud platform. I want access the same with my host ip or container ip or any other ip which can be accessed to others on same network

Comment: @Karan, In windows, docker runs on a small VM and inside this, the containers will be running. So if we do -p hostPort:containerPort, then it might be exposed to the VM instead of Windows PC.

Comment: did you try this 0.0.0.0:Port?